# Markov Chain exercise in an exam

Tags: random-variable, markov-chain, random-walk

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, X_3... $ is a Markov chain with the following transition matrix:

State:

```
  | 1   2   3 
--+-----------
1 |0.2 0.4 0.4
2 |0.5 0.0 0.5
3 |0.6 0.3 0.1
```

(forgive my attempt at a table if you can)

Calculate expectation and variance of $ S_n = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 ... + X_n $

This seems like a random walk to me where I do not know the distribution of the random variable that will follow. I can't use the linearity of the expected value if I don't know what probability distribution $ X_i $ will take on, this is the only way I know to find an expected value of a random walk so I am stumped.

Comment: You do know the distribution of the random variable that will follow given that you know the current value; it's in the transition matrix.  Do you know the probabilities of the initial state ($X_1$)?  If so, you can calculate all the probabilities iteratively.

Comment: The exercise does not give a starting state, this seems weird to me. Maybe the professor corrected it during the exam, I must admit that even with a starting state I would have trouble having never seen such an exercise in class.